# Logging: Logger does not log to file but to console

Tags: python, logging, celery

I am trying to configure a logger for my Celery based application.
The console logging works fine. However, the logs messages are not added to my specified log file: `celery.log`.

- **Why the log messages are not written to the log file?**

Here is my **logging configuration**

```
# log_config.py    

import sys

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s',
             'datefmt': '%y %b %d, %H:%M:%S',
            },
        },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'WARN',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'stream': sys.stdout,
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
        'celery': {
            'level': 'WARN',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': '/tmp/celery.log',
            'formatter': 'simple',
            'backupCount': 5,
            'maxBytes': 1024 * 1024 * 100,  # 100 mb
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'celery': {
            'handlers': ['celery', 'console'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level': 'WARN',
        },
    }
}
```

Celery and log initializiation:

```
dictConfig(log_config.LOGGING)
app = Celery('app',
             broker=env('CELERY_BROKER_URL', 'amqp://'),
             backend=env('CELERY_BACKEND_URL', 'rpc://'),
             include='tasks')
```

Sample Output

```
[2016-05-04 12:32:45,077: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@computer1 ready.
[2016-05-04 12:32:47,503: WARNING/Worker-2] [INFO] Running plugin `one` with target `www.example.com`
[2016-05-04 12:32:47,508: WARNING/Worker-1] [INFO] Running plugin `two` with target `www.example.com`
[2016-05-04 12:32:47,559: WARNING/Worker-3] [INFO] Running plugin `three` with target `('127.0.0.1', 'example.com')`
[2016-05-04 12:32:47,559: WARNING/Worker-3] tasks.MySampleTask[31ffe71d-4645-47f2-1237-4c431282ac12]: it works!
```

**PS**: I don't use Django.

Comment: Where does the sample output come from? it doesn't match the format defined in the 'simple' formatter.

Comment: - The first comes directly from celery. The lines 2 to 4 are done through simple printing. The last line is from `from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger` -> `logger = get_task_logger(__name__)
` and `logger.warn('it works!')`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER` setting to use your custom logger.

```
app.conf.update(CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER=False)
```

If you restart worker, it will generate a celery log file.

You can read more about [this in celery docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#logging).